# Binding WPF Listview colums with powershell pipeline for output

Tags: wpf, powershell

I’m working on a PowerShell WPF GUI tool where I’m stuck with binding pipeline output to listview…I have gone through couple of blogs/articles but couldnt find way to pass pipeline output to listview columns.

I have attached code from xaml and powershell...
xaml code:

```
<ListView Name="listdisk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="415" Margin="20,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="830" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"> 
<ListView.View>
 <GridView> 
  <GridViewColumn Header="Server Name" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'ServerName'}" Width="200"/>
  <GridViewColumn Header="C Disk Size(GB)" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Csize'}" Width="105"/>
  <GridViewColumn Header="C Free Space(GB)" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Cfree'}" Width="105"/>
  <GridViewColumn Header="C % Free Space" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'CPercentfree'}" Width="100"/>
  <GridViewColumn Header="D Disk Size(GB)" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Dsize'}" Width="105"/>
  <GridViewColumn Header="D Free Space(GB)" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'Dfree'}" Width="100"/>
  <GridViewColumn Header="D % Free Space" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'DPercentfree'}" Width="100"/>
 </GridView> 
</ListView.View> 
</ListView>
```

Powershell function-

```
Function Get-diskinfo{
$dsk=@()
$Getservers = Get-Content $dsksvr
foreach ($CompName in $Getservers)
{

$cdrivespace= Get-WMIObject Win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $CompName |  ?{$_.DeviceID -eq 'C:'} | Select @{Name=‘cTotalSize’;Expression={[int]($_.Size / 1gb)}},`
@{Name=‘cFreeSpace’;Expression={[int]($_.FreeSpace / 1gb)}}, @{Name=‘cPercentFree’;Expression={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size,2)*100}}


$ddrivespace= Get-WMIObject Win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $CompName |  ?{$_.DeviceID -eq 'D:'} | Select @{Name=‘dTotalSize’;Expression={[int]($_.Size / 1gb)}},`
@{Name=‘dFreeSpace’;Expression={[int]($_.FreeSpace / 1gb)}}, @{Name=‘dPercentFree’;Expression={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size,2)*100}}

     $diskinfo = New-Object psobject
        Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "ServerName" -value $CompName
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "cSize" -value $cdrivespace.cTotalSize
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "cFree" -value $cdrivespace.cFreeSpace
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "cPercentfree" -value $cdrivespace.cPercentFree
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "DSize" -value $ddrivespace.dTotalSize
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "DFree" -value $ddrivespace.dFreeSpace
     Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "DPercentfree" -value $ddrivespace.dPercentFree
     $dsk +=$diskinfo

} Return, $dsk
}
```

This is the part where I'm thinking am not doing it properly...can someone guide me on this please..? Thanks

```
$btndiskinfo.Add_Click({
get-diskinfo | % {$listdisk.items.add([pscustomobject]($_))}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `{Binding WhatEverYouWant}` instead of `{Binding 'WhatEverYouWant'}`,

When you need to pass a custom object in a listview you can use :

```
$btndiskinfo.Add_Click({
    $listdisk.ItemsSource = @(get-diskinfo)
})
```

Be sure your columns names in the listview have the same name as your custom object properties

Answer (score 0):

I've got a work-around you can try. Instead of creating an array of PSObjects inside the foreach and adding it to the ListView after the function is over, try creating 1 PSCustomObject  like you're already doing but instead add it to the ListView then and there where you call `$dsk += $diskinfo`

Something like:

```
...
Add-Member -InputObject $diskinfo -membertype noteproperty -name "DPercentfree" -value $ddrivespace.dPercentFree
$listdisk.items.add([pscustomobject]($diskinfo))
```